# Scrapy: How to set scrapy start_urls from a setting file?

Tags: scrapy

Normally you provide hard coded `start_urls` but what if I want to mention certain listing url one at a time?

I know I can make a typical text file open operation but wonder whether there's some *Scrapy way* to perform the task?

`start_urls` will be saved in file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you put your config files inside the spiders directory and config dir. So overall path `scrapy_project -> spiders -> configs-> <spider_name>.txt`

Then you can override **init** of your spiders to populate your start_urls something like this.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "configs/%s.txt" % self.name)
    with open(abs_file_path) as f:
        self.start_urls  = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: You should use `pkg_resources.resource_string('package', 'subdirectory')` instead; e.g. `self.start_urls = pkg_resources.resource_string('mycrawler', 'data/urls.txt').splitlines()`.

Comment: Also don't forget to add the super method to call the constructor:
`super(SpiderClassName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it, but you have to modify `__init__()` of your spider:

```
from scrapy import Spider
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'start_urls'
    start_urls = ['http://google.com']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if isinstance(self.start_urls, str):
            self.start_urls = self.start_urls.split(',')

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Now you can modify the start_urls by passing comma separated list via `-a` argument:

```
scrapy crawl start_urls -a "start_urls=http://stackoverflow.com,http://httpbin.org"
```

Unfortunately AFAIK you can only pass arguments as string via `-a` argument so you need to handle interpretation yourself (in this case convert string into list since start_requests() iterates through start_urls value, if it's a string it will iterate through every character and break).

Comment: I have clarified the question. The URLs will be in text file.